# Sinatra settings lost in class scope

Tags: ruby, scope, sinatra, settings

For a Sinatra application config.ru invokes "run" in the following class:

```
class My_init < Sinatra::Base
    # Define all environments available in our app

    # Set the applications root directory

    # Define Root Path

    # Require all files in the App directory

    # Load database configuration

    require './config/database'

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      :adapter  => "mysql2",
      :host     => settings.db_host,
      :database => settings.db_name,
      :username => settings.db_username,
      :password => settings.db_password
    )
end
```

For some reason, the settings load from ./config/database are not accessible from this scope. If I print the settings from the configuration file itself like "p settings.db_host" everything is ok, however, inside this class, settings.db_host is unknown.

Does someone know what is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what your `./config/database` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Ruby > 1.9.2, `require` does not look at the current directory.

You should try using `require_relative 'config/database'` or add the current directory to the load path: `$LOAD_PATH << '.'`.